# The embedded page has viewport, how to make iframe responsive?

Tags: iframe, viewport, responsive

The embedded page has bellow "viewport":

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-scale=0.45, maximum-scale=0.45, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=high-dpi">
```

It's responsive when I open this page in device's browser(iPhone5). But when I embed it inside an iframe it's not responsive.

How can I make my frame responsive for this page?